# How do I parse XML with Nokogiri css selectors, using loops?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to parse this sample XML file:

```
<Collection version="2.0" id="74j5hc4je3b9">
  <Name>A Funfair in Bangkok</Name>
  <PermaLink>Funfair in Bangkok</PermaLink>
  <PermaLinkIsName>True</PermaLinkIsName>
  <Description>A small funfair near On Nut in Bangkok.</Description>
  <Date>2009-08-03T00:00:00</Date>
  <IsHidden>False</IsHidden>
  <Items>
    <Item filename="AGC_1998.jpg">
      <Title>Funfair in Bangkok</Title>
      <Caption>A small funfair near On Nut in Bangkok.</Caption>
      <Authors>Anthony Bouch</Authors>
      <Copyright>Copyright © Anthony Bouch</Copyright>
      <CreatedDate>2009-08-07T19:22:08</CreatedDate>
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword>Funfair</Keyword>
        <Keyword>Bangkok</Keyword>
        <Keyword>Thailand</Keyword>
      </Keywords>
      <ThumbnailSize width="133" height="200" />
      <PreviewSize width="532" height="800" />
      <OriginalSize width="2279" height="3425" />
    </Item>
    <Item filename="AGC_1164.jpg" iscover="True">
      <Title>Bumper Cars at a Funfair in Bangkok</Title>
      <Caption>Bumper cars at a small funfair near On Nut in Bangkok.</Caption>
      <Authors>Anthony Bouch</Authors>
      <Copyright>Copyright © Anthony Bouch</Copyright>
      <CreatedDate>2009-08-03T22:08:24</CreatedDate>
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword>Bumper Cars</Keyword>
        <Keyword>Funfair</Keyword>
        <Keyword>Bangkok</Keyword>
        <Keyword>Thailand</Keyword>
      </Keywords>
      <ThumbnailSize width="200" height="133" />
      <PreviewSize width="800" height="532" />
      <OriginalSize width="3725" height="2479" />
    </Item>
  </Items>
</Collection>
```

Here is my current code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("sample.xml"))
somevar = doc.css("collection")

#create loop
somevar.each do |item|
  puts "Item "
  puts item['Title']
  puts "\n"
end#items
```

Starting at the root of the XML document, I'm trying to go from the root "Collections" down to each new level.

I start in the node sets, and get information from the nodes, and the nodes contain elements.  How do I assign the node to a variable, and extract every single layer underneath that and the text?

I can do something like the code below, but I want to know how to systematically move through each nested element of XML using loops, and output the data for each line. When finished showing text, how do I move back up to the previous element/node, whatever it may be (traversing a node in the tree)?

```
puts somevar.css("Keyworks Keyword").text
```

Comment: So what do you want to capture when you parse the XML? Parsing it and traversing it is fine, but we need to know what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: checkout this sax parsing options, http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/ New OX ruby parser seems to be 5 times faster than Nokogiri, https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri's `NodeSet` and `Node` support very similar APIs, with the key semantic difference that `NodeSet`'s methods tend to operate on all the contained nodes in turn. For example, while a single node's `children` gets that node's children, a `NodeSet`'s `children` gets all contained nodes' children (ordered as they occur in the document). So, to print all the titles and authors of all your items, you could do this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("sample.xml"))

coll = doc.css("Collection")

coll.css("Items").children.each do |item|
  title = item.css("Title")[0]
  authors = item.css("Authors")[0]
  puts title.content if title
  puts authors.content if authors
end
```

You can get at any level of the tree in this way. Another example -- depth-first search printing every node in the tree (NB. the printed representation of a node includes the printed representations of its children, so the output will be quite long):

```
def rec(node)
  puts node
  node.children.each do |child|
    rec child
  end
end
```

Since you ask about this specifically, if you want to get at the parent of a given node, you can use the `parent` method. You may never need to though, if you can put your processing in blocks passed to `each` and the like on `NodeSet`s containing subtrees of interest.

Comment: Michal,
Your answer really helped me :)

The only thing that is tripping me up now is how can you select an attribute from a given tag.  
For example, on some of those tags we had "width" and "height"
How can you get the value of those using your code?

Comment: There's a number of methods for extracting attributes from nodes; for example, `attributes` gets you a hash of attributes and values (with namespaces stripped from the attributes; see `attribute_nodes` if that's a problem), `each` iterates over attribute name/value pairs (that's `each` directly on the node, as opposed to on the return value of `children`) etc. See [the API docs for Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) for details.